# ASP.net webgrid loses jquery hover after sort

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor

EDIT:
It seems that when I put @DateTime.Now within the html to be "ajaxUpdateContainerId", the value changes on click of grid header. The grid loses binding of hover.

I have a WebGrid object, using **WebMatrix** Razor C WebPages, that when sorted loses the jquery toggleClass declaration. Here is some sample js code to help.

```
function reBindHover(){
    $('#result tbody').on("hover","tr", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    reBindHover();   }
```

The server side code from my .cshtml page.

```
var signgrid = new WebGrid(datasignstatus, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "result", 
    //ajaxUpdateCallback: "addCheck", 
    ajaxUpdateCallback: "reBindHover", 
    rowsPerPage: 20);
```

How does this need to work so I maintain hover after sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Performing a Sort causes a PostBack, so you need to rebind the `hover` functions by calling your `reBindHover` after sorting.

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //rest of the code that does the sorting

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "reBindHover", "reBindHover();", true);
}
```

Comment: Is the WebPages Razor WebGrid different from MVC?